# The link is opening with right click, not with left click in Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms

When my data grid view load it contains these methods:

and here is the code of **bold** method:

```
   private void LoadDataGridViewData()
   {
       SalaryGridView.ClearSelection();
       this.SalaryGridView.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.SalaryGridView_DataError);
       SalaryGridView.DataSource = GetBasicSalaryForAllEmployees();
       SalaryGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
       SalaryGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
       SalaryGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
       SalaryGridView.GridColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
       SalaryGridView.CurrentCell = null;
       DataGridEditImageColumn.AddImage(SalaryGridView);
       DataGridEditImageColumn.AddLinkButton(SalaryGridView, "SalaryColumn", "Add Employee Details", "lnkColumn", "Details");
       SalaryGridView.Columns["BasicSalaryId"].Visible = false;
       SalaryGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
       Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
       ViewHistory = new ToolStripMenuItem("View Past Transactions");
       ToolStripMenuItem AddAllowance = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add Allowance");
       ToolStripMenuItem AddBonus = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add Bonus");
       AddAllowance.Click += new EventHandler(AddAllowance_Click);
       ViewHistory.Click += new EventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
       AddBonus.Click += new EventHandler(AddBonus_Click);
       Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ViewHistory, AddAllowance, AddBonus });
       SalaryGridView.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
       StoreInitialColumnVisibility();
   }
```

```
 public static void AddLinkButton(DataGridView dataGridView,string Name,string Text,string DataPropertyName,string Header = "")
 {
     DataGridViewLinkColumn lnkColumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
     lnkColumn.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
     lnkColumn.Name = Name;
     lnkColumn.Text = Text;
     lnkColumn.HeaderText = Header;
     lnkColumn.DataPropertyName = DataPropertyName;
     lnkColumn.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
     dataGridView.Columns.Add(lnkColumn);
 }
```

So, when I try to access forms via link, I have to click **right** on mouse instead of left click.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGdgi.png)

Here I have to change the click from **right** to **left**

Comment: I think I have to do changes on this method:

DataGridEditImageColumn.AddLinkButton(SalaryGridView, "SalaryColumn", "Add Employee Details", "lnkColumn", "Details");

Comment: Normally, the DataGridViewLinkColumn should react to a left mouse click by default. If you have to use a right mouse click, then it's likely that something is intercepting or overriding the default behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have used this method on other forms too, and they work perfectly fine but not in this grid. Or gotta find the proporties.